# Net connection drops/freezes when steam loads

Tags: steam

Whenever I connect to Steam my internet appears to freeze for a couple of minutes. Now I realise that a game updating can take up bandwidth which would slow my connection but surely I should still be able to load a page in my firefox browser. My net connection doesnt die based on the my modems' lights but the page fails to load. If I leave it a minute or even a couple of seconds it then seems to connect.

Im not having issues with playing online with Steam, it just appears to be a lapse that occurs when initially loading Steam.
It appears to be random and in some cases Steam loading doesnt affect my connection at all. I have noticed it more when a game is updating hence I made the link.

Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: I have a similar problem - when Steam loads, it takes up so much resources for my old computer that it cannot do much else. Webpages don't load during this time - not because Steam dropped the connection - but because the CPU just doesn't have the resources to load any webpages in my normal browser until Steam finishes it's initialization.

Comment: Also, check this out : http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1250142

Comment: Thanks rlb.usa , at least I know Im not alone! Sadly my current pc should (in theory) be able to handle Steam > 3gigram/Core2QuadQ6600. Really frustrating issue!